# Unable to run `apt-get` commands in Dockerfile "executor failed running"

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apple-m1, alpine-linux, bullseye

Working on OSX, zsh within iTerm2.

I have a .sh script to build a Docker container. It was originally being built using openjdk Alpine but I transitioned to Bullseye such that it works with M1 chips on Mac. I'm now running into an issue where these lines in the file don't run:

```
 18 # Install git as additional requirement
 19 RUN apt-get update && \
 20     apt-get upgrade  && \
 21     apt-get install git && \
 22     apt-get install bash
```

When running this I get the following error:

```
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get upgrade  &&     apt-get install bash]: exit code: 1
.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR while building docker container!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
USAGE:
docker/buildDocker.sh [TAG_NAME]
```

I'm fairly new to Docker but I'm a bit confused as to why this is. With Alpine these RUN commands were `apk` so I simply changed them to `apt-get` to match Bullseye's package manager. Using `apt` results in the same error. Have I done something wrong? I'm not even sure of the proper terminology here so apologies for ay errors. Here is the full Dockerfile:

```
# START GLOBAL DECLARATION
####################################################
ARG REPO_NAME_DEFAULT=[REDACTED]
ARG REPO_PORT_DEFAULT=8040
ARG SERVICE_ROOT_DIRECTORY_DEFAULT=/spring/
####################################################
# END GLOBAL DECLARATION
####################################################

####################################################
# Building environment (java & git)
####################################################
FROM openjdk:16-bullseye AS build-env-java
LABEL maintainer=[REDACTED]
LABEL stage=build-env

# Install git as additional requirement
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade  && \
    apt-get install git && \
    apt-get install bash

####################################################
# Building service
####################################################
FROM build-env-java AS [REDACTED]
LABEL maintainer=[REDACTED]
LABEL stage=build-contains-sources

# Fetch arguments from above
ARG REPO_NAME_DEFAULT
ARG SERVICE_ROOT_DIRECTORY_DEFAULT

# Declare environment variables
ENV REPO_NAME=${REPO_NAME_DEFAULT}
ENV SERVICE_DIRECTORY=$SERVICE_ROOT_DIRECTORY_DEFAULT$REPO_NAME

# Create directory for repo
RUN mkdir -p /git/${REPO_NAME}
WORKDIR /git/${REPO_NAME}
COPY . .
RUN cp settings/application-docker.properties settings/application-default.properties
# Build service in given directory
RUN bash ./build.sh $SERVICE_DIRECTORY

####################################################
# Runtime environment 4 [REDACTED]
####################################################
FROM openjdk:16-bullseye AS [REDACTED]
LABEL maintainer=[REDACTED]
LABEL stage=run

# Fetch arguments from above
ARG REPO_NAME_DEFAULT
ARG REPO_PORT_DEFAULT
ARG SERVICE_ROOT_DIRECTORY_DEFAULT

# Declare environment variables
ENV REPO_NAME=${REPO_NAME_DEFAULT}
ENV SERVICE_DIRECTORY=${SERVICE_ROOT_DIRECTORY_DEFAULT}${REPO_NAME}
ENV REPO_PORT=${REPO_PORT_DEFAULT}

# Install bash as additional requirement
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade  && \
    apt-get install bash

# Copy service from build container
RUN mkdir -p ${SERVICE_DIRECTORY}
WORKDIR ${SERVICE_DIRECTORY}
COPY --from=[REDACTED] ${SERVICE_DIRECTORY} ./

# Define repo port 
EXPOSE ${REPO_PORT}
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "./run.sh"]
```

Comment: "Exit code 1" just means "it didn't work"; is there more error above that?  For these two specific packages, can you check out source code on the host instead (so you don't need `git`) and limit yourself to POSIX shell syntax for your scripts (so you don't need `bash`)?

Comment: It helps if you can include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): that is, the smallest amount of code (in this case, your `Dockerfile`) required to reproduce the problem. There's a a lot of content here that doesn't seem relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we try building from the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:16-bullseye AS build-env-java

# Install git as additional requirement
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade  && \
    apt-get install git && \
    apt-get install bash
```

It will fail with this error:

```
[...]
After this operation, 15.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get upgrade  &&     apt-get install git &&     apt-get install bash' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

As you can see `apt-get` is attempting to prompt for interactive input, but because it's not an interactive environment the command fails. We need to tell `apt-get` to install without prompting by adding the `-y` flag to the `upgrade` command. The `install` command will need the same treatment:

```
FROM openjdk:16-bullseye AS build-env-java

# Install git as additional requirement
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y upgrade  && \
    apt-get -y install git bash
```

I've consolidated your multiple `apt-get install` commands into a
single command (because that will generally be faster), but you can of
course continue to use multiple commands if you wish.

This `Dockerfile` builds without errors.